# How to send custom headers in websocket creation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

So I had the following code on Python that created a websocket connection:

```
channels_dict = {}
channels_dict['Authorization'] = 'true'
for channel in channels: #adds some extra headers with info
    channels_dict["Channel" + str(channel)] = '1'

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:8888/ws",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close,
                              header = channels_dict)
```

And I could easily add extra headers that I could access later in the server upon connection. Is there a way I could do the same in Javascript? I haven't found much information about setting custom headers in websocket creation. I have the following code in JS:

```
var webSocket;

function openWebsocket() {
  webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/ws")
}
```

I've heard of adding query parameters in the url, is that the only way of adding extra headers/information to a websocket connection in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 const webSocket = new WebSocket ("ws://localhost:8888/ws"  + "?param1=" + param1); // here you can add other params
 webSocket.on("open", function open(e) {
   console.log("*** websocket opened");
 });
```

Comment: Ok, now I did this: ```webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/ws?param1=yooo")```. The server I'm connecting to is basically a Tornado Server but I don't think that matters much. In the next comment I'll put the headers I receive and print in the server when it receives the websocket connection attempt.

Comment: ```Host: localhost:8888
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: chrome-extension://aegbhodkdcknhkiimijaibmipgknpphb
Sec-Websocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Sec-Websocket-Key: V7K2QUIifuqI37ao0VZCHA==
Sec-Websocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits```

Comment: I don't think these url params are added to the headers, I'm gonna search where can I access them in the server.

Comment: Ok, I think I can access them in the server by the uri I receive. But it's gonna be a little more complicated because I have to analyze the uri string to search for the parameters. Before I was just searching them in the headers dictionary which was very easy.